# How to display ecore Eclass names for content assist in Xtext editor after generating artifacts ?

Tags: dsl, xtext, emf

**Aim:**  To provide editor for configuring a pattern rule for Fruits.ecore

DSL Rule will some thing like this     **“A Grade” + Apple.name**

**Problem:**   With new instance of eclipse application I created a sample project and  created a file  with  **text.fruit**   within this editor I need to creat my new Fruit rule

**EClass** name and **EStructural** feature as my content assist

When I  do **Ctrl + Space**  my expectations  to get list  as content assist

1. Apple
2. Orange

**Steps taken:**

1. Created an xtext plug-in with extension .fruit as my fruit.xtext as dsl.
2. Using import statement  in my “fruit.xtext” file

   ```
           import “platform:/resource/com.emf.sample/model/Fruits.ecore” as ecore
   ```
3. Within  fruit.xtext content assist of ecore works
4. Now generate Xtext artificats and run the application

Model for above scenario :

[image]

How to add external ecore as part of Content assist in Work Flow or Grammar of xtext editor ?  Any sample examples or work around will help .

Thanks

Comment: It seems this confuses two different levels ob abstraction. Where you refer to EClasses in Xtext's grammar editor, your DSL will refer to instances of EClasses. Why would you want to show the EClasses themselfes and where / at which cursor position would you like to see those?